# golang: winapi call with struct parameter

Tags: windows, winapi, networking, go, dll

I'm trying to call `WinHttpGetIEProxyConfigForCurrentUser` function to get the automatically detected IE proxy settings. It accepts an inout struct parameter according to [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384096(v=vs.85).aspx). I'm using following code:

```
func GetProxySettings() {
    winhttp, _ := syscall.LoadLibrary("winhttp.dll")
    getIEProxy, _ := syscall.GetProcAddress(winhttp, "WinHttpGetIEProxyConfigForCurrentUser")

    settings := new(WINHTTP_CURRENT_USER_IE_PROXY_CONFIG)
    var nargs uintptr = 1

    ret, _, callErr := syscall.Syscall(uintptr(getIEProxy), nargs, uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&settings)), 0, 0)
    fmt.Println(ret, callErr)
    if settings != nil {
        fmt.Println(settings.fAutoDetect)
        fmt.Println(settings.lpszAutoConfigUrl)
        fmt.Println(settings.lpszProxy)
        fmt.Println(settings.lpszProxyBypass)
    }
}

type WINHTTP_CURRENT_USER_IE_PROXY_CONFIG struct {
    fAutoDetect       bool
    lpszAutoConfigUrl string
    lpszProxy         string
    lpszProxyBypass   string
}
```

It looks like the call is successful, `settings` is not nil, but as soon as I access it I get panic. Here's the output:

```
1 The operation completed successfully.
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xc0000005 code=0x0 addr=0x1 pc=0x4d2bb4]
```

Comment: A Go string is not the same as a C string, and in this case the docs look like the fields are supposed to be wide chars (?), so those should probably be `*uint16` instead of string. You are also passing a pointer to a pointer to the syscall, which only requires a single pointer. get rid of the extra `&` in the arguments.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. How do I convert the `*uint16` to a go string? I've found `UTF16PtrFromString` doing the opposite conversion, but nothing to convert back.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to pass a pointer to your allocated struct, which you already created with the `new` function. Remove the extra `&` from the syscall; `uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(settings))`

You also need to have a struct that has the same layout as the C struct expected by the syscall. The struct definition looks like:

```
typedef struct {
  BOOL   fAutoDetect;
  LPWSTR lpszAutoConfigUrl;
  LPWSTR lpszProxy;
  LPWSTR lpszProxyBypass;
} WINHTTP_CURRENT_USER_IE_PROXY_CONFIG;
```

Which should translate to

```
type WINHTTP_CURRENT_USER_IE_PROXY_CONFIG struct {
    fAutoDetect       bool
    lpszAutoConfigUrl *uint16
    lpszProxy         *uint16
    lpszProxyBypass   *uint16
}
```

Each of those `LPWSTR` fields is going to be a null-terminated, 16bit/char string. For windows you can generally use the syscall `UTF16` functions, but here we first need to convert the `*uint16` to a `[]uint16` slice, then decode that slice to a utf8 string. There function that the syscall pakcage uses to do this isn't exported, but we can easily copy that:

```
// utf16PtrToString is like UTF16ToString, but takes *uint16
// as a parameter instead of []uint16.
// max is how many times p can be advanced looking for the null terminator.
// If max is hit, the string is truncated at that point.
func utf16PtrToString(p *uint16, max int) string {
    if p == nil {
        return ""
    }
    // Find NUL terminator.
    end := unsafe.Pointer(p)
    n := 0
    for *(*uint16)(end) != 0 && n < max {
        end = unsafe.Pointer(uintptr(end) + unsafe.Sizeof(*p))
        n++
    }
    s := (*[(1 << 30) - 1]uint16)(unsafe.Pointer(p))[:n:n]
    return string(utf16.Decode(s))
}
```

Or use the exported version that was recently added to `golang.org/x/sys/windows`, [`windows.UTF16PtrToString`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/sys/windows?tab=doc#UTF16PtrToString).

Comment: Pro tip: string conversion is a lot easier with `syscall.UTF16ToString`.

Comment: @Rodrigo: It does not make it _a lot_ easier, it only does half the work here of decoding the utf16, you still have a `*uint16` to `[]uint16` conversion to make, which is exactly what the unexported `utf16PtrToString` function does. Now that I think about it, I should just copy that function in since it doesn't leave the overflow prevention as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 1):

You take the address of an address here:

```
// The type of settings is *WINHTTP_CURRENT_USER_IE_PROXY_CONFIG
settings := new(WINHTTP_CURRENT_USER_IE_PROXY_CONFIG)

// ...

// The type of &settings is **WINHTTP_CURRENT_USER_IE_PROXY_CONFIG
ret, _, callErr := syscall.Syscall(uintptr(getIEProxy), nargs, uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&settings)), 0, 0)
```

Remove the `&` from `Syscall` call an it should work.

Comment: You are right. However there's still problem with the type of `lpszProxy`. `string` doesn't seem to be right. I tried `*uint16`, but I cannot find a way to convert it to string.